# Находится ли адрес в определенной зоне

Tags: яндекс-карты

Требуется узнать, находится ли адрес человека в определенной зоне (допустим КАД)
Возможно ли это реализовать с помощью yandex map?

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/delivery_zones